# Is there a keyboard shortcut for the “pause animation” feature in Chrome Developer Tools? (F12)

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, css, animation, developer-tools

There is a nifty feature in Chrome's Developer Tools which allows you to pause animations and control their speed, but the problem is they're mouse-controlled buttons. Sometimes I need to pause an animation without actually moving the mouse cursor to inspect something inside a hover-activated animation, so I can't really use the pause button. Is there a keyboard shortcut for that animation pause button so I don't need to move the cursor off whatever I'm doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As previously mentioned, there's no keyboard shortcut to pause an animation, but I've found the next best thing: Using Ctrl+Shift+C (Cmd+Shift+C in Mac) to enable inspecting while the cursor is on the element with the hover activated animation. That doesn't stop already running animations, but prevents further mouse activated animations from triggering while inspecting, which might be enough to inspect an element.

Answer (score 1):

The Developer Keyboard Shortcuts can be found at [Keyboard Shortcuts](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/shortcuts).

Unfortunately there doesn't appear to be one for "Pause Animation" unless it is called something else.